# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE does not insert rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.  It is showing blank output and no insertion in mySQL DB.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pwd*")or die("cannot connect");

mysql_select_db("my_db")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.csv' INTO TABLE usersystem 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
      IGNORE 1 LINES
      (email,password,fname,lname)";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
    echo "DONE"
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
```

Why doesn't it insert rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pwd*") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("my_db") or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.csv' INTO TABLE usersystem" .
       " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'" .
       " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'" .
       "  IGNORE 1 LINES" .
       " (email,password,fname,lname)";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
  echo "DONE"
}

else {
  echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection
mysql_close();
```

**WARNING**

---

The `MySQL` extension is horribly outdated! Either use `MySQLi` or `PDO`. For learning them, use your favorite search engine.

Comment: You used `+` sign to concatenate the sql query string, `.` use in PHP to concatenate the string.

Comment: @Jahanzeb  Oh thanks, what a fail! I did too much JavaScript in the past ;)

Comment: horribly outdated but works. I am bored to read it in every post.

Comment: thanks for help but Still Blank out put and no insertion in DB

Comment: Everyone knows that, yet not everyone wants to spend hours rewriting his old code with no benefit. If you start new project then fine,  but when maintaining old the code which works there is no actual reason, from project mgmt perspective. Yet everyone here cries like paranoid "don't use that!!"

Comment: @zohaib Have you tried executing the SQL on the command line? And @@Tomas: I do **not** know his project, its status, its code or whatever. I just wrote these two sentences, are they really that annoying? Yet some people cry for two sentences.